# HTML -- Multiple Input Type Variables in Single Link

Tags: html

I am writing a java servlet in which I need to set multiple variables into a link. The I wrote is as follows:

```
 sb.append("<td><a href=\"return?typeId="
                        + checkOutId 
                        + ",otherId=" + user.getId() 
                        + ",date=" + "Today"
                        + "\">    Return"
                        + "</a>" 
                        + "</td>"
                        + "</tr>");
```

But its error-prone. Is there a way I can set multiple input types within a single link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off doing these things using a template based framework like knockout or Angular or similar. It let's you bind javascript objects to your DOM without having to do dynamic javascript based DOM building